# How to remove the empty space between divs in CSS?

Tags: css, html

I am building a very simple website to refresh my self in basic HTML and CSS. I am using Dreamweaver CS6. I am looking to learn every aspect the 'right' way. I think that I can use margins to move the divs where I want them (up or down) but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to achieve it.

Here is an example. I took a screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fslb3.png

There is a gap between the header and the top of the container div. There is a gap between the content div and both the header and footer div.

How can I make these divs flush with each other removing the gap? Thanks!

NOTE: I have researched al the other questions on this site similar to this but none are exactly this nor do their answers solve this issue in it's most basic form.

EDIT: Got a bunch of different answers with everyone saying their way is right. This has confused me. And I'm not getting answers to each one of their initial posts. I am curious as to why these divs are not by default flush with each other. I will be creating more divs later in the site. If I don't understand why your method works I won't be able to implement it on more divs on the site. Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Dreamweaver. Please provide code. Preferably via jsFiddle. Also what do you mean by flush?? Also, we can't do much with Dreamweaver's 'code' view. At the very least show us the 'design' view.

Comment: Flush: to make flush or even. to be touching at the border. The screenshot and image i posted shows both the code and the design view. In jsfiddle you can not see the divs them selves so i took a screenshot while in dreamweaver. But seense you asked I made a quick jsfillde. http://jsfiddle.net/aztek/NbP4x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're looking for. You still need to play around with things, obvs. But see if this is a good start for you. I added `background color` to show the sections. You can remove.

http://jsfiddle.net/NbP4x/1/

Here's a good tutorial on making your first website - using Dreamweaver. Start here man. :)
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/first_website_pt1.html

Comment: Yes your way worked as well. Which is now confusing the heck out of me, lol. Everyone says their way is right. and the guy above said the guy who said he was right was wrong. May I ask why your version of code worked and why it's different than the others? Is it the proper way? Why are they not already flush by default? Thanks

Comment: Also What will I have to do in the future to make ALL my divs flush? I'm deff going to want all the divs i make to be flush by default.

Comment: Check this other jsFiddle i did. http://jsfiddle.net/NbP4x/2/. I also updated my answer with a tutorial link.

Comment: What's the difference in both your fiddles? The second one still only styles the 4 divs in my code. Both your methods worked fine. My question is now, if i introduce another div into my code what ill I have to do to make that div flush as well?

Comment: Just add another DIV with a class or ID. http://jsfiddle.net/NbP4x/3/. Gotta play with it man. Trust me, go through the tutorial. You'll learn a ton of the basics and your question won't be as foreign.

Comment: Yeah ima have to read the tutorial. Cause i see that you made the new div a CLASS rather than an ID. Not sure why. Also why do you write out the css like this div#header rather than just this #header works both ways?

Comment: lol I did that to mess with ya a bit. It'll all make sense soon...hit the books, learn and good luck!

Comment: Classes can be applied to more than one element to style them. IDs must be unique and you can't apply IDs to multiple DOM elements (i.e DIVs and such).

Comment: No prob! Happy coding! Challenge yourself and do 5 random tutorials on building a website. By the end, you'll be one step closer to being a pro. :)

Comment: Hey, Mike are you still there? I have one last question for you?

Comment: Is there a way to send messages on here? My question was a bit long and I didn't want to cluster up this question page

Answer (score 1):

it's because  has default style, you use

```
h1{margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
```

can fix it.

i suggest you reset all default style by

```
*{margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
```

and more reset css, I mightily you may should see [enter link description here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

for more detail :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added your suggestion to my code *{margin: 0px;padding: 0px;} and it worked. So thank you much for the help. Now that I have it fixed and working could you tell me WHY it worked and why resetting defaults is something you should do? Thanks again. Like I said I want to know the proper ways to program now. To get into good habits. The whys are important to me. =)

Comment: Setting `margin:0` and `padding:0` to all everything is not the right way to go about it. It'll result in more CSS code as he starts to develop. Obvs he want some padding on the headers and `<p>`. IMO.

Comment: Mike Barwick If this is not the correct way could you tell me why please/ I have heard 5 different answers. Now I am confused. =/ Who's way is right? and why is that way right? Thanks

Comment: For someone starting out, which clearly you are. Resets are not your best solution. Resets work best when you already have a default base for headers, paragraphs, list-items, etc. If you don't understand what his code does above, it's only going to cause more issues for you down the road, IMO.

Comment: "The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on. The general reasoning behind this was http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/ "

Comment: Mike, I see what you mean and I agree. If I'm not familiar enough with it it will casue me more problems as I'll have to code with that in mind and If i don't understand it I can anticipate it. Do you have an solutions Mike? What would you do?

Comment: Yeah, I know how resets work, but I don't think he does. Having the `*{}` applied to everything is just going to make him come back here and ask why there's no spacing in an ordered list or something lol. You know? He needs to start with the basics, imo.

Comment: Check my answer...I put a tutorial in there. That tutorial has been around for YEARS and is updated constantly as times "change". I actually learned to code my first site from that (I think).

Comment: Looking at the tutorial Mike, Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Eric Meyer reset is one of the 'right ways' to do it, much better than using the *

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>North Carolina Golf Car Dealers</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
#container {
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Header goes here.</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="content">
            <p>Content goes here</p>
         </div>
         <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer goes here.</p>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally you should keep the HTML and CSS separate by using an external style sheet:

So the HTML: index.html (for example)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>North Carolina Golf Car Dealers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Header goes here.</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="content">
            <p>Content goes here</p>
         </div>
         <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer goes here.</p>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS: style.css (for example)

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
#container {
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note: I changed your CSS #container from:

```
    #container {
     width: 960px;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto
```

to:

```
    #container {
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

combining the margin-right and margin-left (both ways work...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used your method and it worked as well. To be honest all the answers up here have worked. Which one is right? I am new to HTML/CSS so if i were to use your code would I have to keep it in mind when continuing to code the site? Meaning, do I need to understand what you have given me in order to continue to write code and program my site? Could you tell me why your code worked and why I should use it over the others please? Thanks!

Comment: This is a good method. But learn the basics dude...none of the code in the answers differ much (ignore the negative vote ones though). It's all basic HTML and CSS. You're not going to learn how to code the basics asking questions via SO. Read a tutorial or two - build sites in those tutorials and it will all click for you. Even this answer is not really going to teach you anything when the basics aren't understood.

Comment: No I agree. I've been doing a ton of HTML and CSS tutorials but they al seem to leave out some basic info here and there like the spaces between the divs, etc,. Maybe i'm just to OCD but it's hard for me to continue intill I know how and why something functions the way it does. I'm going to go do the tutorial you linked tho. And thanks a lot mike for  having patience with me!.

Comment: @user2833068 You are absolutely right in being confused. I had the same problem. The reason is that browsers automatically add some margins around some elements and hence the divs are not flushed (because browsers added the margins). The answers here are basically telling you to remove those default margins and padding added by browsers. The answer you have currently accepted is immediately answers your question, but this answer is the "right" way IMO because it resets everything. Feel free to ask more if you are still interested after all these years :)

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it's a line-height issue, not a space between the divs. Try adding a border to divs and see if they touch.

div {
border : 1px solid black;
}

Comment: Adding the border did in fact make them touch and are now flush. So it's a step better but I don't want to have borders on my divs. In dreamweaver and the image i linked shows a dotted border around divs but that's just in design mode. Not when it's live. Any idea how to make them flush/touching without giving them borders? Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

I think it is the characteristics of 'p', try to remove the 'p' inside div#content, I think the gap can be removed.